# How to pass props to form in another component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying somehow to pass pre-defined form data via $router.push, so when that link is clicked, some pre-defined data/props should be defined in the form like dropdrown or just pass some data into input form

I tried different methods, but nothing made it work, can someone please help me?

Input in another Vue component where I want to pass data:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="">
```

Click Router:

```
<ul>
  <li @click="clickRouter(path)"> Click here </li>
</ul>

data() {
    return {
      path: '/products',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clickRouter(link) {
      this.$router.push(link);
    },
  },
```

Update:
According to [Programmatic Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html) you can do this:

```
// with query, resulting in /register?plan=private
router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' }})
```

now this URL ?plan=private I want to be able to do something like `/register?name=Myname`

And this shall prefill the name input in the component.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What methods did you try?

I see two possibilities:

1. set a property in the parent component
2. use vuex

the `clickRouter`-method would set the property and then bind it in the `input`-field.

**Update:**

index.js (router):

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import register from "@/components/register";

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/register",
            name: "register",
            component: register
        }
    ]
});
export default router;
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <header>
            <button @click.stop.prevent:="clickRouter(path)">Go to register</button>
        </header>
        <main>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "app",
        data () {
            return {
                path: '/register',
                prefill: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            clickRouter(link) {
                this.prefill = 42;
                this.$router.push({ path: link, query: { plan: 'private' }});
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**register.vue:**

```
<template>
    <input <input type="text" name="" :value="prefill">
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            prefill() {
                return this.$parent.prefill;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I would not use vuex, it would get to complicated I guess. How should I use property in the parent component ? I don't get it ? The vue component where I want to pass data to is a search filter/form, and the clickRouter would just need to pass some pre-defined search results, like main category etc... and there are several categories

Comment: The router is not responsible to pass state around, and it should not be. It's job is to change UI depoending on the URL, and it should work in a way that is not dependent on local data from the previous component.

If you need to share state between distant components, that sounds like you need some form of shared state management, for which the professional solution would indeed be vuex, but there are simple solutions as well, like this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch

Comment: I just updated my question to give more details @LinusBorg, if that is not possible than I will consider the simple state management or passing value via vuex

Comment: @mathias can you please show me an example on how would clickRouter set the property than bind it to the input field ?

Comment: @MathiasNater Thnx for your answer, I just saw your answer. Thnx for your time